# multi display issues. bug? user? idk... you tell me

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, display

my chipset says i have 3 gpu clock generator. no mention of usb-c video in laptop manual.

i want to have 3 displays. built-in laptop and 2 externals one hooked by hdmi and one by usb-c-dvi adapter. whenever i am in displays menu i only ever see two monitors. hdmi and built-in.

i dont know if linux isn't seeing my display adapter, if it isn't sending video over usb-c or if my monitor is broken. idk. i will test the monitor later.

why can't i see any buttons or interface info on whether the third monitor is even possible? i dont know of  a way to check if video is even being sent out of the usb-c hole.

i am on the latest ubunut 18.10 and using default gnome.

FINALLY: when i have my setup for using only one monitor (plugged in monitor) if i unplug this monitor the built-in one doesn't automatically turn on. is this normal? you want to have a setting that disables the main (and at times ONLY) display? why? why is this a thing? i will report as a bug unless someone explains why this is even a thing that exists. very bad design if it is on purpose.

thanks for your help.

Comment: moving known-functioning monitor to the usb-c dongle also produces no video.